# How to set another layout for first listView item?

Tags: android, listview

I created listView with CustomAdapter. I am trying set another layout for first item of list view. I tried by position but its not helped. any suggestions?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;

    Log.d("Position: ",String.valueOf(position));
    if (convertView == null) {
        if(position==0)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, null);
        else
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.nTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        holder.nDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listDate);
        holder.nCategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listCategory);
        holder.nImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listImage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    if (newsList.get(position) != null) {
        holder.imageUrl = newsList.get(position).image;
        holder.nTitle.setText(newsList.get(position).title);
        holder.nCategory.setText(newsList.get(position).category);
        holder.nDate.setText(Base.getInstance(aContext).getDateString(newsList.get(position).date));
        holder.nImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.photo_bg);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

My template:
[image]

Comment: use `setHeader` method

Comment: If you want a image at the top. You can design you layout having image at the top and listview below it. That would be simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that

Have the below in the adapter

```
private static final int TYPE_ITEM1 = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM2 = 1;
```

Override `getItemViewType`

```
int type;
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position== 0){ // position 0 
        type = TYPE_ITEM1;
    } else {
        type = TYPE_ITEM2;
    }

    return type;
}
```

And Override `getViewTypeCount`

```
 @Override
 public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2; // we have 2 types
 }
```

In `getView`

```
  int type = getItemViewType(position);
    // instead of if else you can use a case
   if (convertView == null)  {
    if (type == TYPE_ITEM1) { 
            //inflate layout of type1
      }
    if (type == TYPE_ITEM2) {
            //inflate layout of type2
    }  
   // Your rest of the code
```

Docs :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29

Also go through this video. Most of the concepts are covered in the talk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Also using `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView` would be better

Comment: FIRST_TYPE? SECOND_TYPE? You mean TYPE_ITEM1?

Comment: its working but not helped. Its same of my code. I wrote your code and in result every time when position is 0 its loading my first layout.

Comment: @iProgrammer you want a different layout @ position 0. Is that what you want. . Is that your requirement am i understanding your problem right?. The item index starts @ 0. So you want to have a layout  `row1.xml` inflated at that position then the above works.

Comment: yes you are right. I just want set another layout only for first item. I uploaded my template image to question.

Comment: @iProgrammer would it not be simple to design your layout holding your image at the top and listview below it. Also the above solution should work. You can also add a header to the listview ( image would scroll along with list).

Comment: you know I am new in android and I dont know how to use header. Can you explain how to use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85386/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-iprogrammer).

Comment: Here: http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/ I found some example. But its not what I want.

Comment: @Raghunandan is it possible to set horizontal lisview in first item position and third item position based on this answer?

Comment: @Naruto looking for something similar http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html. Can be done with recyclerview

Comment: @Raghunandan just now looked at your comment.surely it will helpful to me.thank you.

Comment: @Raghunandan Thank you for your suggestion.with the help of that horizonatal  recyclerview inside vertical recyclerview is working good.

Answer (score 1):

If only the first item is different than other items in the `ListView`, it's advisable to use `addHeaderView` instead of inflate it in the `getView`. First inflate that view in your `Activity` or `Fragment` then update add it to that listview.

Follow [this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean))